# Convert if else into ternary in ruby slim(temple engine)

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I have this code

```
- value="true"

- if (value)
  p yes #if the condition is true I want to insert a glyphicon. (<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>)
- else
  p no
```

How to convert it into `condition? <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> : <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>`

But this is causing error!

Comment: Do you want a version of that code that uses the ternary expression, or are you asking about inserting the `i` tag mentioned in the comment? Is this in Haml or Slim? What are `yes` and `no`? Do you mean to use `"true"` (a string) or did you mean `true` (the Boolean)?

Comment: I want to print out yes and the icon in that para. And this is ruby slim, since there is no existing tag for slim, I mentioned as HAML cos the syntax is similar.

Comment: String yes along with the icon into the HTML page? stuck with this for 2 hours now :(

Comment: Should the "yes" be in a `<p>` element? If so should the `i` be inside it too?

Comment: its working if I write if else statement, but I want to perform the same thing using ternary operator. i.e condition? <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> : <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>

Comment: Why does it need to be a ternary? I don’t think that it is possible with a ternary using slim syntax, maybe if you use literal html.

Comment: @Ajey, shouldn't my answer work? That is, add quotes around the HTML tags.

Comment: @matt well it can be done using normal if/else but I prefer ternary because it takes less lines of code and serves the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code can simply be replaced with this:

```
= value ? "yes" : "no"
```

Any lines starting with `=` are evaluated, and the resulting return value is inserted into the document after a call to `escape_html`.

Because you explained in your comments that you actually want HTML code to be inserted, you'll have to do this:

```
== value ? '<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>'
```

Comment: when I add quotes, it is being interpreted as string and the output is <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> rather than the icon.

Comment: @Ajey: Ahaaa, the single quotes escape the HTML (I thought this was Haml, but I see you changed the tags afterwards). Use double quotes instead? I've updated my answer.

Comment: bang on mate! but how do I output the icon ?

Comment: @Ajey: Updated again: Try == instead of =, as the latter calls `escape_html` and the former does not.